# How to improve Flex performance for invisible views

Tags: performance, apache-flex

We have a medium size Flex 3.6 application that contains around 20 different page views (managed via a single lazy ViewStack) each having multiple components. Most use custom renderers.

All model data is loaded at startup and changes to model instances are communicated via binding and/or collection change events.

Once the user has viewed each page at least once, all page views are instantiated and happily listen to update events.

**Which in effect means that each time a model instance changes, all interested views receive that event and compute derived data or trigger item-renderers.**

I have tested and confirmed this behaviour in a proof-of-concept application. Even when setting a list to being invisible, it still listens to collection change events and invalidates any renderer affected.

What would you do?

Comment: Flex 3.6 doesn't exist as far as I know, so is it 3.5 or 4.6?

Comment: There's a lot of resources out there regarding optimization for flex mobile development but the main thing I'm seeing/thinking here is you should be using a ViewNavigator not a ViewStack http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/View+and+ViewNavigator

Comment: @RIAstar [Flex 3.6 SDK](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex3sdk) does exist... I have one of my projects compiled with it!

Comment: @JonathanRowny Ah lovely Adobe transparency: that version is nowhere to be found on the [Flex SDK download page](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Downloads) and Flex 3.5.0.12683 is mentioned as the latest milestone release. (And your link to the 3.6 download is located under ColdFusion: now it all makes sense... )

Comment: @RIAstar Yea, it used to be on that page, not sure why its not now. It is on the Flex SDK download site, its just in a sort of abandoned state over here: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3

Comment: @shaunhusain The application is not written for mobile devices but is rather an ordinary RIA browser application

Comment: @Tom thanks for clarifying, just have had my blinders on thinking about mobile development.  I think J_A_X, probably has the best solution below, you may need to write a "deactivate" method for each view that removes the listeners that are used to update the view, then an "activate" method to attach listeners etc to make sure the view can be garbage collected (needs to have no strong references in the object graph for this to happen).  This could be triggered using the show/hide events or with a overridden set visible I believe.  Also profile to focus your effort on worst offenders.

Answer (score 1):

Having a singleton for your views is not a recommended way of doing things because it keeps everything in memory, which can be massive.  You should destroy all views appropriately after their use.  You should be more vigilant around memory management overall on your system.  Also, you should "deactivate" parts of your system that aren't currently in use.

I would recommend that you remove anything from the view that isn't currently needed unless it's appropriate to "preload" them for certain uses.  You should also look at the profiler (if you have it) to see what is using the most memory and try to fix the code that's using too much of it.